# postgresql Rails native gem extension failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rubygems, pg

I am trying to create a new rails-api project. I begin with the following command `rails-api new <name> -T -d postgresql`, to which I receive the following:

```
Gem files will remain installed in /var/folders/lk/2ckzjmfx03sgkryx70nc3_c40000gn/T/bundler20151231-18995-t8e1f5pg-0.18.4/gems/pg-0.18.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/folders/lk/2ckzjmfx03sgkryx70nc3_c40000gn/T/bundler20151231-18995-t8e1f5pg-0.18.4/gems/pg-0.18.4/ext/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.18.4'` succeeds before bundling.
         run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:347:in `block in verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!': Could not find gem 'pg (>= 0) ruby' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

I follow up with a `sudo gem install pg -v '0.18.0'`, to which I receive the following error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/local/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

At this point I am unsure on what I can do. I can locate the path of `/usr/local/bin/pg_config` I just dont know how to solve this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I also attempted `ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386" bundle install` (same result) & `ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" bundle install` and got:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin/pg_config
Using config values from /usr/pgsql-9.2/bin/pg_config
sh: /usr/pgsql-9.2/bin/pg_config: No such file or directory
sh: /usr/pgsql-9.2/bin/pg_config: No such file or directory
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... yes
checking for PQconnectionUsedPassword()... yes
checking for PQisthreadsafe()... yes
checking for PQprepare()... yes
checking for PQexecParams()... yes
checking for PQescapeString()... yes
checking for PQescapeStringConn()... yes
checking for PQescapeLiteral()... yes
checking for PQescapeIdentifier()... yes
checking for PQgetCancel()... yes
checking for lo_create()... yes
checking for pg_encoding_to_char()... yes
checking for pg_char_to_encoding()... yes
checking for PQsetClientEncoding()... yes
checking for PQlibVersion()... yes
checking for PQping()... yes
checking for PQsetSingleRowMode()... yes
checking for PQconninfo()... yes
checking for rb_encdb_alias()... yes
checking for rb_enc_alias()... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl()... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_with_gvl()... yes
checking for rb_thread_fd_select()... yes
checking for rb_w32_wrap_io_handle()... no
checking for rb_str_modify_expand()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for PGRES_COPY_BOTH in libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for PGRES_SINGLE_TUPLE in libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for PG_DIAG_TABLE_NAME in libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for struct pgNotify.extra in libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for ruby/st.h... yes
checking for C99 variable length arrays... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
compiling gvl_wrappers.c
compiling pg.c
compiling pg_binary_decoder.c
pg_binary_decoder.c:52:1: warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
pg_binary_decoder.c:83:1: warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
2 warnings generated.
compiling pg_binary_encoder.c
compiling pg_coder.c
pg_coder.c:24:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
1 warning generated.
compiling pg_connection.c
compiling pg_copy_coder.c
compiling pg_errors.c
compiling pg_result.c
compiling pg_text_decoder.c
compiling pg_text_encoder.c
compiling pg_type_map.c
compiling pg_type_map_all_strings.c
compiling pg_type_map_by_class.c
compiling pg_type_map_by_column.c
compiling pg_type_map_by_mri_type.c
compiling pg_type_map_by_oid.c
compiling pg_type_map_in_ruby.c
pg_type_map_in_ruby.c:145:1: warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
1 warning generated.
compiling util.c
linking shared-object pg_ext.bundle
ld: file not found: dynamic_lookup
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [pg_ext.bundle] Error 1
```

I again appreciate any time you may spend helping me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiling native extensions requires some development libs to be installed via system installer.

```
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
```

The library was installed by `homebrew` when you installed `postgresql`. But you didn't specify correct architecture, that's why it wasn't found. After specifying `x86_64` the lib was found:

```
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... yes
```

but his time wrong `pg_config` was used:

```
Using config values from /usr/pgsql-9.2/bin/pg_config
sh: /usr/pgsql-9.2/bin/pg_config: No such file or directory
sh: /usr/pgsql-9.2/bin/pg_config: No such file or directory
```

So you need to specify it manually, like so:

```
ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config
```

Comment: This is for Ubuntu. OP operations system is OS X. Only OS X has a path like `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/` to the system ruby.

Comment: @Jeiwan Me not specifying the path manually seemed to be the problem. After running `ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config